# PHPStorm no se detiene en los breakpoints ni muestra los valores de variables

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

hace ya varios días estoy luchando para hacer funcionar PHPStorm con XDebug en mi entorno sin suerte. Les paso a detallar como está mi configuración:

Primera parte: información del contexto

**Apache 2.4**

**PHP 7.1.1**

**Path de instalación del XDebug:** C:\AppServ\php7\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.1-vc14.dll

**Del phpinfo:** "This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans"

**Configuración en el php.ini:**

> [Xdebug]
>
> zend_extension = C:\AppServ\php7\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.1-vc14.dll
>
> xdebug.remote_autostart=1
>
> xdebug.default_enable=1
>
> xdebug.remote_port=9000
>
> xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
>
> xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
>
> xdebug.remote_enable=1
>
> xdebug.remote_mode=req
>
> xdebug.remote_log=C:\AppServ\php7\log\xdebug.log

Segunda parte:

1. Cree un proyecto de PHP en PHPStorm con un solo archivo index.php que tiene el siguiente código para poder hacer unos breakpoints simples:

> $variable = 1000;
>
> echo 'hola mundo';
>
> echo $_SERVER['remote_addr'];
>
> $variable = 1250;
>
> echo $variable;

1. En PHPStorm voy a Run->Edit Configurations...aquí completo los datos, elijo en server (Localhost puerto 80)
2. Hago click en Validate debugger, todo sale en verde
3. Hago click en el icono del teléfono para iniciar el listener, agrego un breakpoint en la linea $variable = 1000;
4. Luego hago click en icono del debugger, se abre el navegador en esta URL http://localhost/prueba/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14107, hace los echos pero nunca salta en el breakpoint marcado y tampoco muestra información de las variables, solo la $_SERVER.

Si reviso el log, todo parece correcto en cuanto a la conexión:

> [2944] Log opened at 2019-06-20 19:00:32
>
> [2944] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
>
> [2944] I: Connected to client. :-)

pero luego me encuentro con este código de error:

```
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>
```

Ya probé todas las opciones habidas y por haber...creo...y sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar. Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos,
Vero

Answer (score 0):

seguí haciendo algunas corridas...sin suerte tampoco pero el log ha cambiado. Si bien sigue sin funcionar el log parecería detectar los breaks pero los pasa de largo:

```
[12900] Log opened at 2019-06-20 21:41:53
[12900] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[12900] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[12900] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[12900] W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9010. :-|
[12900] I: Connected to client. :-)
[12900] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/AppServ/www/prueba/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.1.29-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="12900" idekey="17228"><engine version="2.7.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[12900]
[12900] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- status -i 5
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="5" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- step_into -i 6
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="6" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///C:/AppServ/www/prueba/index.php" lineno="9"></xdebug:message></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file://C:/AppServ/www/prueba/index.php -n 9
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="129000001"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t line -f file://C:/AppServ/www/prueba/index.php -n 13
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="129000002"></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- stack_get -i 9
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="9"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///C:/AppServ/www/prueba/index.php" lineno="9"></stack></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- stack_get -i 10
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="10"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///C:/AppServ/www/prueba/index.php" lineno="9"></stack></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- context_names -i 11
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="11"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- context_get -i 12 -d 0 -c 0
[12900] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="12" context="0"><property name="$variable" fullname="$variable" type="uninitialized"></property></response>
[12900]
[12900] <- context_get -i 13 -d 0 -c 1
[12900] -> <response
```